# conditional formatting table jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a quiz with 9 skills, and 1 skill has 2 questions - total 18 questions
So when ppl submit the quiz, the result table returns 4 ranges (Rangea,b,c,d). So based on the score, I want to highlight the row for each skill

result table
[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
    var sum = 0;
    var numberQA = 2
    $('.skillA:checkbox').click(function() {
        sum = 0;
        $('.skillA:checkbox:checked').each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
        });             
        average = sum / numberQA;   
        $('#totalSkillA').html(average);            
    });

    $('tbody tr td:not(":third")').each(
        function() {
            var rangeA = 1,
                rangeB = 2,
                rangeC = 3,
                rangeD = 4,
                score = $(#totalSkillA).value();

            if (score < rangeA) {
                $(#totalSkillA).addClass('avg');
            }
            else if (score < rangeB && score >= rangeA) {
                $(#totalSkillA).addClass('avg');
            }
            else if (score >= rangeB && score < rangeC) {
                $(#totalSkillA).addClass('avg');
            }
            else if (score >= rangeC && score <= rangeD) {
                $(#totalSkillA).addClass('avg');
            }
        });
```

So for example I have 3 questions with Q1,2,3 having value 1,2,3 and I did the average of these values. So now the average = score . I have 4 ranges as in the code, so I want if the score is in RangeA , the cell will be highlighted

SO if the score is in rangeA, I want the table highlight that section

Comment: If you execute your own snippet you can see that you have a very obvious syntax error

Comment: SyntaxError: illegal character[Learn More]. This is what i get  at the line score = $(#totalSkillA).value(),

Comment: Exactly. You need to provide the selector as a string: `$('#totalSkillA').value()`. I'd suggest you read jQuery basics at http://learn.jquery.com. Your `if` statement also seems needlessly complicated given that all the if/else blocks perform the same action

Comment: Could you help me to fix it please

Comment: The #totalSkillA is getting the average of total score, so how to turn it into string

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. You simply need to add quotes around the selector in the jQuery object. In other words, change all instances of `$(#totalSkillA)` to `$('#totalSkillA')`. If you have another issue I'd suggest being much clearer about what it is you're attempting to do

Comment: I did but there is an error SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}' In skill A if the score is in Range A I want the section of Range A have a background color yellow, if it's inj range B i want the section of Range B have a background color yellow

Comment: Which is...? Youre really not making it easy to help you

Comment: So for example I have 3 questions with Q1,2,3 having value 1,2,3 and I did the average of these values. So now the average = score . I have 4 ranges as in the code, so I want if the score is in RangeA , the td will be highlighted

Answer (score 0):

Update your js code. There is an issue in all lines e.g. $('#totalSkillA').addClass('avg'); with single quotes

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    var sum = 0;
    var numberQA = 2
    $('.skillA:checkbox').click(function() {
        sum = 0;
        $('.skillA:checkbox:checked').each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
        });             
        average = sum / numberQA;   
        $('#totalSkillA').html(average);            
    });

    $('tbody tr td:not( ":third")').each( function() {
            var rangeA = 1,
                rangeB = 2,
                rangeC = 3,
                rangeD = 4,
                score = $('#totalSkillA').value();

            if (score < rangeA) {
                $('#totalSkillA').addClass('avg');
            }
            else if (score < rangeB && score >= rangeA) {
                $('#totalSkillA').addClass('avg');
            }
            else if (score >= rangeB && score < rangeC) {
                $('#totalSkillA').addClass('avg');
            }
            else if (score >= rangeC && score <= rangeD) {
                $('#totalSkillA').addClass('avg');
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: SyntaxError: illegal character[Learn More]. This is what i get  at the line score = $(#totalSkillA).value(),

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
    var sum = 0;
 var numberQA = 2
    $('.skillA:checkbox').click(function() {
        sum = 0;
        $('.skillA:checkbox:checked').each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
        });    
  average = sum / numberQA;   
  $('#totalSkillA').html(average);      
    });
    
 $('tbody tr td:not(":third")').each(
  function() {
   var rangeA = 1,
    rangeB = 2,
    rangeC = 3,
    rangeD = 4,
    score = $(#totalSkillA).value();
   
   if (score < rangeA) {
    $(#totalSkillA).addClass('avg');
   }
   else if (score < rangeB && score >= rangeA) {
    $(#totalSkillA).addClass('avg');
   }
   else if (score >= rangeB && score < rangeC) {
    $(#totalSkillA).addClass('avg');
   }
   else if (score >= rangeC && score <= rangeD) {
    $(#totalSkillA).addClass('avg');
   }
  });
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body, td, th, input {
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 11px;
}

.avg {
    background-color: #060;
}

.liveSample {
 background-color: #FFFFCC;
 color: black;
 padding: 4px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.demoDiv {
 background-color: #CCCCCC;
 width: 2000px;
}
.highlited {
 background-color: #FFFFCC;
 color: #000000;
}
.grayBG {
 background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

pre {
 font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
 background-color: #F0F7FE;
 padding: 5px;
 overflow: auto;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
 }
h3 {
 background-color: #F3F3F3;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 font-size: 100%;
 line-height: 150%;
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-bottom-color: #CCCCCC;
}
h4{
 color: #000099;
 font-variant: small-caps;
 font-size:120%;
}
td, th{
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-bottom-color: #CCCCCC;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 padding-left: 10px;
}
th {
 background-color: #F3F3F3;
 vertical-align: top;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<form name="readiness" method="post">
        
        Navigate:
        <a href="#" onclick="sp5.showFirstPanel(); return false;">First</a> |
        <a href="#" onclick="sp5.showPreviousPanel(); return false;">Previous</a> |
        <a href="#" onclick="sp5.showNextPanel(); return false;">Next</a> |
        <a href="#" onclick="sp5.showLastPanel(); return false;">Last</a>
        </p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <div id="example5" class="SlidingPanels" tabindex="0">
            <div class="SlidingPanelsContentGroup">
        
                <div class="SlidingPanelsContent p1">
                        <div class="demoDiv" style="background-color: #E6E6E6">
                            <table width="650">      

     <!-- Skill A -->
                        <!-- Question 1 -->       
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="400">
                                        <h4>1. My need to take this course now is:</h4>
         
                                        <p><input class="skillA" type="checkbox" value="4" name="q1A" id="q1" onclick="if(this.checked) {document.readiness.q1B.checked=false;document.readiness.q1C.checked=false;document.readiness.q1D.checked=false;} showHide('feedback1', this);"/> A. High. I need it immediately for a specific job goal.</p>
                                        <p><input class="skillA" type="checkbox" value="3" name="q1B" id="q1" onclick="if(this.checked) {document.readiness.q1A.checked=false;document.readiness.q1C.checked=false;document.readiness.q1D.checked=false;} showHide('feedback1', this);"/> B. Moderate.  I could take it on campus later or substitute another course.</p>
                                        <p><input class="skillA" type="checkbox" value="2" name="q1C" id="q1" onclick="if(this.checked) {document.readiness.q1A.checked=false;document.readiness.q1B.checked=false;document.readiness.q1D.checked=false;} showHide('feedback1', this);"/> C. Low. It could be postponed. </p>
          <p><input class="skillA" type="checkbox" value="1" name="q1D" id="q1" onclick="if(this.checked) {document.readiness.q1A.checked=false;document.readiness.q1B.checked=false;document.readiness.q1C.checked=false;} showHide('feedback1', this);"/> D. Low. It could be postponed. </p>
                                    
         </td>
                                    <td width="250">
                                        <div id="feedback1" style="visibility:hidden">
                                        <strong>Why this is important:<br></strong> Generally, the more urgently you need to take an online course, the more motivated you'll be, and therefore more successful. If you have a strong reason for taking an online course, like a job goal, you're more motivated to spend the time to complete it.
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                        <!-- End question 1 -->
                            
                        <!-- Question 2 -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="400">
                                        <h4>2. Considering my work and personal schedule, the amount of time I have to work on an online course is:</h4>
                                    
                                        <p><input class="skillA" type="checkbox" value="4" name="q2A" id="q2" onclick="if(this.checked) {document.readiness.q2B.checked=false;document.readiness.q2C.checked=false;document.readiness.q2D.checked=false;} showHide('feedback2', this);" />A. More than for a traditional course at the college.</p>
                                        <p><input class="skillA" type="checkbox" value="3" name="q2B" id="q2" onclick="if(this.checked) {document.readiness.q2A.checked=false;document.readiness.q2C.checked=false;document.readiness.q2D.checked=false;} showHide('feedback2', this);" />B. The same as for a traditional course at the college.</p>
                                        <p><input class="skillA" type="checkbox" value="2" name="q2C" id="q2" onclick="if(this.checked) {document.readiness.q2A.checked=false;document.readiness.q2B.checked=false;document.readiness.q2D.checked=false;} showHide('feedback2', this);" />C. Less than for a traditional course at the college.</p>
          <p><input class="skillA" type="checkbox" value="1" name="q2D" id="q2" onclick="if(this.checked) {document.readiness.q2A.checked=false;document.readiness.q2B.checked=false;document.readiness.q2C.checked=false;} showHide('feedback2', this);" />D. Less than for a traditional course at the college.</p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="250">
                                    <div id="feedback2" style="visibility:hidden">
                                    <strong>Why this is important:<br></strong> Allowing more study time while you're taking an online course is a good idea, partly because it may take a while to get used to the way it works, and partly because there's generally more reading and writing to do in online courses. Of course, when you work on your course is up to you.
                                    </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
       </div> 
                        <!-- End question 2 -->                        
     <!-- End Skill A -->
```